# Rotating the Rectangle object in java

Tags: java, rotation

Is it possible to rotate the `Rectangle` object to a certain degree around it's axis? Is it as easy as `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h,r)`?

If it is not possible to rotate the object, what would be a way I could get similar results?

**Edit:** for clarity here is my dilemma, I have images that rotate but when they colide with other images the collisions only work at 90 and 180 degree rotations because their hit box Rectangle objects don't rotate.

Comment: Look up use of AffineTransform.

Comment: I don't need to visually rotate the object, I need to rotate the Hit Box for the image and the hit box is a Rectangle Object

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. AffineTransforms ***are*** used for rotating Rectangles.

Comment: let me try this out in code before i keep talking.

Comment: How would I rotate the Rectangle? the code below uses graphics while I need to use the actual Rectangle Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: for clarity here is my dilemma, I have images that rotate but when they colide with other images the collisions only work at 90 and 180 degree rotations because their hit box Rectangle objects don't rotate.

You can rotate a Shape-derived object, such as a Rectangle2D by using the AffineTransform method, [`createTransformedShape(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-).

```
Rectangle2D myRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 200);
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 4, 150, 150);
Shape rotatedRect = at.createTransformedShape(myRect);
```

Note: code not compiled nor tested.

Comment: `createTransformedShape(new Rectangle(x,y,w,h))`? I am not trying to do anything visual with my rotated rectangles and it seems like all these example involve visual reshaping

Comment: Ok, sorry I just associate Rectangle2D with Graphics, after reading the documentation on Shapes, Rectangle2D, AffineTransform, and a few others I understand. Sorry for the complication.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the rectangle, you give the graphics context an `AffineTransform` for rotation. Here's an example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(radians);
    g2d.draw(rectangle);
    g2d.setTransform(oldTransform);
}
```

You can also use `g2d.rotate(radians)` for rotation.

Note that the angle must be in radians. To convert degrees into radians, use `degrees * (Math.PI/180)` for the angle.

Comment: I can draw rotated shapes just fine, the problem is their hitboxes don't rotate with the shape, creating funky physics

Comment: Consider using `getTransform()` as per the [AffineTransform tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) rather than `setTransform`, and don't forget to re-set the original transform. Either that or make a copy of the Graphics object, transform and draw with that, and then dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way to do this (besides [`createTransformedShape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-)) which creates fewer temporary objects, if that's desirable.

Instead of keeping a `Rectangle2D` for the bounding box, you can keep a [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) and then do the transform in place, using [`Path2D.transform(AffineTransform)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#transform-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-):

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Example {
    private final Path2D hitBox;

    public Example(Rectangle2D initialHitBox) {
        this.hitBox = new Path2D.Double(initialHitBox);
    }

    public void transform(AffineTransform tx) {
        path.transform(tx); // In-place transformation.
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is very similar to [what `AffineTransform` actually does under the hood](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.java#AffineTransform.createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29).